# Excel If this and that then

Tags: excel

I have two tabels looking like this:
[image]

As you can see I have an empty column "OSAKAAL". I want excel to copy the correct values there, so if it finds exactly the same "KR_kood" and "Aasta" value on the left which is on the right table also, then it copies the "OSAKAAL2" value to the "OSAKAAL" cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multi-criteria Index/Match for this.  Make sure to enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> as it's an array formula.

In `Q2`, you can use:

```
=INDEX($J$2:$J$7,MATCH($O2&$P2,$L$2:$L$7&$K$2:$K$7,0))
```

(Adjust the ranges as necessary).

Answer (score 2):

You may try this Regular Formula which doesn't require any special key stroke.
In Q2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$1000,MATCH(O2&P2,INDEX($L$2:$L$1000&$K$2:$K$1000,),0)),"")
```

Adjust the ranges used in the formula as per your requirement.